# VS Code : variables in custom snippet

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

How do I create a custom snippet that will automatically enter a variable's value that I type into its prefix?

I want a snippet that will create a html start-end tag comment block. For example if I type `/se hello` I want the result to be

```
<!-- $var start-->

<!-- $var end-->
```

Where `$var` is replaced with "hello". Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [VSCode snippet docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) says, it uses [TextMate](https://macromates.com/manual/en/snippets) to power its snippets. TextMate uses variables of the form `$name` and `${name:default}`, and luckily supplies `$TM_CURRENT_WORD` which may be sufficient for your needs. However there is no built in variable to get multiple arguments directly after the snippet name i.e. `$arg1` and `$arg2` as variables. Thought you could do a similar effect with interpolated shell code, but unfortunately:

> The snippet syntax follows the TextMate snippet syntax with the **exceptions of 'interpolated shell code'** and the use of \u; both are not supported.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

However for this simple example, the following indexed variable example is probably sufficient.

```
<!-- $1 start-->
    $0
<!-- $1 end-->
```

`$i` gives you a value to fill in, you can go between each one with tabbing. The `$0` is where the cursor goes at the end(the end of the snippet by default). Optionally you can do something like:

```
<!-- ${1: default text} start-->
    $0
<!-- $1 end-->
```

and it'll start looking like:

```
<!-- default text start-->

<!-- default text end-->
```

with both of the defaults selected to edit.

This all put together would look like this together in the `snippets.json` file:

```
{
    "se": {
        "scope": "html",
        "prefix": "se",
        "body": [
            "<!-- ${1:default text} start-->",
            "\t$0",
            "<!--$1 end-->"
        ]
    }
}
```

As @Mark pointed out, if you want it to work for more than just HTML you can use `$BLOCK_COMMENT_START` and `$BLOCK_COMMENT_END` which will vary for each language. The snippet would then look like this:

```
{
    "se": {
        // Leaving scope off will make it a global snippet
        "prefix": "se",
        "body": [
            "$BLOCK_COMMENT_START ${1:default text} start $BLOCK_COMMENT_END",
            "\t$0",
            "$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$1 end $BLOCK_COMMENT_END"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest `"$BLOCK_COMMENT_START $1 start $BLOCK_COMMENT_END",` and `"$BLOCK_COMMENT_START $1 end $BLOCK_COMMENT_END",` - it'll work in more file types than just html. And with the `$0` in the middle line.  It'll insert the proper comment types automatically.

Comment: I hadn't been thinking about making it language agnostic, and since it's an important point I've incorporated it into my answer now to give it more visibility, thanks!